# Application does not fetch data from firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

The application does not pick up data from the firestore.
The application is supposed to be created in the form of a tinder
The application develops the creation of vacancies and resumes. and after creating a resume, vacancies should be selected. and vice versa. But during the selection, the application does not select data from the firestore for me
code for creating a resume and saving it, if anything, saving vacancies is similar to this

```
  if (user != null) {
            // Получаем уникальный идентификатор пользователя
            uid = user.getUid();
        }

        Add_image_btn = findViewById(R.id.button_select_image);
        foto = findViewById(R.id.imageLogin);
        ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> choosePhotoLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                        if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                            Intent data = result.getData();
                            if (data != null) {
                                Uri photoUri = data.getData();
                                // загрузка фотографии в Firebase Storage
                                FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
                                StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();
                                photoRef = storageRef.child("images/" + uid + ".jpg");
                                foto.setImageURI(photoUri);
                                UploadTask uploadTask = photoRef.putFile(photoUri);
                                uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                        photoRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                                photoUrl = uri.toString();
                                                // сохранение URL в Firestore
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        // обработка ошибки загрузки
                                        Log.e("TAG", "Ошибка загрузки: " + e.getMessage());
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

Add_image_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        choosePhotoLauncher.launch(intent);
    }
});



        Save_btn = findViewById(R.id.Save_btn);
        Save_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                foto = findViewById(R.id.imageLogin);
                Full_name = findViewById(R.id.Full_name);
                String name = Full_name.getText().toString();
                profession = findViewById(R.id.Profession);
                String prof = profession.getText().toString();
                birthday = findViewById(R.id.birthday);
                String day = birthday.getText().toString();
                experience = findViewById(R.id.experience);
                String work_experience = experience.getText().toString();
                contacts = findViewById(R.id.contacts);
                String contact = contacts.getText().toString();
                skills = findViewById(R.id.skills);
                String skill = skills.getText().toString();
                dop_info = findViewById(R.id.dop_info);
                String dopinfo = dop_info.getText().toString();
                education = findViewById(R.id.education);
                String my_education = education.getText().toString();
                portfolio = findViewById(R.id.portfolio);
                String my_portfolio = portfolio.getText().toString();
                citizenship = findViewById(R.id.citizenship);
                String my_citizenship = citizenship.getText().toString();
                Map<String, Object> resumeData = new HashMap<>();
                resumeData.put("photoUrl", photoUrl);
                resumeData.put("name", name);
                resumeData.put("profession", prof);
                resumeData.put("birthday", day);
                resumeData.put("experience", work_experience);
                resumeData.put("contacts", contact);
                resumeData.put("skills", skill);
                resumeData.put("dop_info", dopinfo);
                resumeData.put("education", my_education);
                resumeData.put("portfolio", my_portfolio);
                resumeData.put("citizenship", my_citizenship);
                FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

                if (user != null) {
                    String uid = user.getUid();
                    db.collection("resume").document(uid)
                            .set(resumeData)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                    // Данные успешно сохранены
                                    Toast.makeText(Create_ResumeActivity.this, "Резюме сохранено", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            })
                            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    // Произошла ошибка при сохранении данных
                                    Toast.makeText(Create_ResumeActivity.this, "Резюме не сохранено", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Log.e("Create_ResumeActivity", "Ошибка при сохранении данных", e);
                                }
                            });
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
```

и код подбора вакансий

```
 if (user != null) {
            String userId = user.getUid();

            resumeRef.document(userId).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                        if (document.exists()) {
                            // Получите данные из резюме пользователя
                            String profession = document.getString("profession");
                            String experience = document.getString("experience");

                            // Определите критерии подбора вакансий
                            // Например, ищем вакансии с определенной профессией и требуемым опытом
                            vacancyRef.whereEqualTo("profession", profession)
                                    .whereEqualTo("experience", experience)
                                    .get()
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                List<MyVacancy> myDataList = new ArrayList<>();
                                                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                                    // Получите данные из документа и создайте объект MyVacancy
                                                    MyVacancy vacancy = new MyVacancy(
                                                            document.getString("imageResource"),
                                                            document.getString("profession"),
                                                            document.getString("name"),
                                                            document.getString("wage"),
                                                            document.getString("experience"),
                                                            document.getString("infoCompany"),
                                                            document.getString("requirements"),
                                                            document.getString("conditions"),
                                                            document.getString("dopInfo"),
                                                            document.getString("contacts")
                                                    );
                                                    myDataList.add(vacancy);
                                                }
                                                // Создайте адаптер с данными из Firestore и установите его для SwipeFlingAdapterView
                                                SwipeFlingAdapterView flingContainer = view.findViewById(R.id.frame);
                                                VacancyAdapter adapter = new VacancyAdapter(getContext(), myDataList);
                                                flingContainer.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Next to this code is creating an adapter for the SwipeFlingAdapterView that could swipe left to right.

Comment: I can also provide the job creation code